# What does clicking the word "`(change)`" do in Google Chrome's Extension "Save to Google Drive"?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

What does clicking the word "**`(change)`**" do, in the window the ["Save to Google Drive" Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) pops after every save for Google Chrome to Google Drive?

[image: "(Change)"] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vn6mtk7JjThMmdRK-Gaj6nwX6Amna91y/view?usp=sharing is the version saved with said tool showing the unknown/unspecified word in question "**`(change)`**".)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting "`(Change)`" goes back to the URL [chrome-extension://gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne/options.html](http://chrome-extension://gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne/options.html) your Settings page, so you can change format (like different angles of a camera, .MHT, .HTML, or Google Docs format, made like for a scientist too) immediately and make sure your Google has multiple formats saved/archived:

[image: Example from my side of "Save to Google Drive Extension Options" behavior]

***Warning: That means it will pop-up a new tab you need to watch for***, it will leave your current position and switch to `Settings`, so please have enough browser system memory. Check Chrome's menus to use `Task Manager' for browser memory leaks, because mine says "100k" (somewhat stable system process reading but even official Google extensions can be volatile and not explain with a mature error message) of memory used. Archiving takes memory.

(I was scared to click the random word "change" could have so many meanings, so I did not know either, and Google should specify that before sharing; "`(change)`" meant "Rename" to me, given the file name is adjacent to the word, however clicking "Rename" sounded saner if I had to guess, which is guaranteed given it is not a documented feature, we *all* had to guess what the dear Googler meant by "`(change)`" just leaving it like that as "`(change)`")

Comment: Google also knows I manually clicked their extension icon every time (zillions) for a week straight (because I could not know), before finally having the courage to click "(change)". A Googler that programmed that for giving a decent description would have saved joules of energy.